# "fatal error: mysql.h: No such file or directory" Compiling mod_auth_mysql-3.0.0

Tags: mysql, apache, debian

I try to build mod_auth_mysql on my debian Wheezy and I got always this error:

```
mod_auth_mysql.c:269:19: fatal error: mysql.h: No such file or directory
```

I have never build package/mod before, I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I have followed [this documentation](http://modauthmysql.sourceforge.net/BUILD) and used this command line :

```
apxs2 -c -lmysqlclient -lm -lz mod_auth_mysql.c
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to compile with -I"/usr/include/mysql", theres mysql.h there probably.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7729/mod-auth-mysql-will-not-compile-under-slackware-13